# How can I turn off Gmail's threaded conversation view?

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations

I mean, threaded conversations are useful, but sometimes I want to view messages the way e-mail clients traditionally did, with each message its own entity.

How can I do that without using an external tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Gmail blog has just announced a new feature that allows you to do this here:

[Turn off Gmail's conversation view](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/09/turn-off-gmails-conversation-view.html)

> Go to the main [Settings page](https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings), look for the "Conversation View" section, select the option to turn it off, and save changes.

Comment: awesome, I was *just* about to post this here. Major change in direction..