# How do you deal with a stacked message separately in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations

In Gmail, when I get a second (or more) message in from the same sender, they stack.  Some of these I want to keep one message, and archive the others.  Also I need to label them differently sometimes.

How can I deal with stacked messages separately?

Comment: You could suggest this feature to the gmail team. Here is the link to that: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs

Comment: @Alex, ok done.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to use Google's Conversation View if you don't want. Then you can do whatever you want with individual messages.

[How can I turn off Gmail's threaded conversation view?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7134/how-can-i-turn-off-gmails-threaded-conversation-view)

Comment: Great suggestion, I'd never looked into this.

Comment: I like the conversation view normally, I just want to remove individual messages that really don't belong together anyway.  Like what just happened, when I placed three separate orders with Amazon on the same day, and it threaded them together.

Comment: You can delete individual messages, but Archiving is for the whole thread.

Answer (score 3):

I've looked into solutions to similar problems before, and I think that the problem is that the threads system is so entrenched in the software that it's difficult if not impossible to organize your mails in any other way.

A less than optimal way of dealing with it would be to forward the messages of the thread to yourself, and in doing so, change the subject line to fit them into your own organizational scheme.  This loses the sender information, but if you wanted to separate all of the emails from Jim Smith about billing, then forwarding them to yourself with both of those items in the subject line would preserve it.  Extra credit if you make filters to do all of the dirty work.

There may be a "Labs" feature in the works for this kind of thing, but I putter through those periodically, and I don't recall this ability in any of them.

Comment: True, it's a core feature of the service. The only thing you can for now is to delete individual messages from a conversation.

Comment: @Alex, yeh, but like the  example in my comment to Al Everett, I can't go deleting my reciepts.  for now I just have to overlabel them.