# Can Gmail auto track replies of emails when conversation view is turned off?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, configuration

I know Gmail for some time now [allows conversation view to be turned off](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/7147/101688), thereby [ungrouping the emails](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7134/how-can-i-turn-off-gmails-threaded-conversation-view).

However, when doing so, any email replied to leaves no marker at all (as best I can tell), that the email was replied to. One can search in the "Sent Mail" to see something was sent, but when viewing the email itself (Note: I use the "Preview pane" from the Labs tab to view it), I do not see anything after I have replied:

1. letting me know I have replied and
2. linking the email to that reply.

I am hoping there is some other setting to do that. Otherwise, this seems to be a serious design flaw in the implementation of the ungroup conversation view setting. Ungrouping by subject is one thing, ungrouping to the point of not associating actual replies to the initial emails is overboard!

NOTE: I realize turning conversation view "on" associates the replies to the emails. My question concerns how they are/can be associated when turned off. I do not want emails with the same subject line grouped (hence why the view is off), but I do want to know which emails I've replied and what that reply is based on looking at the original email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time the GMAIL web UI can't. The alternatives are to use a POP or IMAP client.

**References**
Gmail Help
http://support.google.com/mail

Gmail Help Forum
[Turning conversation view OFF causing another problem: I can't see my replies in email threads.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/2ibgV2hGXKM)

Comment: I was afraid this was the answer, but I did not locate the relevant threads to confirm it. So your links were most helpful (even if it was not the answer I was hoping for).